How can Managing Multiple Layouts in a Single Activity on Android Studio
I'm trying to develop a quiz game where you have to guess all the members of a football team. In short, the formation opens and the user enters a new activity (with a new layout) through an ImageButton. Inside that activity, they guess the name of the player, then when they go back, the formation layout should reopen and update the corresponding image (for example, if they guess the "LB," the ImageButton btn_lb updates with the relative image).
How can I do this? Thanks in advance!
I tried using the fragment system, where I created a fragment for each player position (e.g., gk_fragment, cb_fragment, etc.), but it doesn't work that way.
